# Bash script to generate lots of ssl/tls connections for performance testing

Tags: bash, shell, ssl, concurrency, tls1.2

I'm currently trying to perf test my application running in production. Specifically, I'm trying to see how many ssl connections my jetty server can handle. Let's call this host `my.webserver.prod.com` and it expects secure traffic on port 443. I would like to write a bash script that I can run from another host and have it generate as many ssl connections as possible. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read a little bit about how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before sharing some of the solutions that you've already attempted.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried till now?

Still you could checkout this tool that bash has `ab`. Its apahce benchmarking. 
This helps in checking performance. And In the end it provides you a summary.

The command goes like :

```
 ab -n 10 -c 2 http://my.webserver.prod.com
```

Where 
 -n -> total number of requests to be made
 -c -> number of concurrent requests

You could do more resarch on this. 
Hope this helps.